# Sub domain handling in codeigniter saas application

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm looking for a best approach to handle sub domains in Saas application. Currently I've a controller which parse the url and decide if the domain is registered then redirect the user to its custom page otherwise send the user to registration page. I want to remove that controller so that any request for www.mydummysite.com land on registration page and any request for subdomain.mydummysite.com land on custom page.